# Prove that $[G:G]=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Very short question:
The exercise is to prove $[G:G]=1$. Now we have a theorem that says $\operatorname{ord}(G)=[G:H]\cdot\operatorname{ord}(H)$ with $G$ a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. The book also says that this theorem holds when $\operatorname{ord}(G)$ is not finite (it says that you then have to work with cardinal numbers).

So can I just say that when we take $H=G$, by theorem, $[G:G]=1$ holds or is my proof lacking something?

Comment: Cardinal arithmetic is far from elementary. It's a good thought, but almost surely not the intended solution. Try to prove the statement directly, i.e. from the definition. I think the point of the exercise is for you to get a better understanding of what $[G:H]$ is.

Comment: It is lacking, because given two non-zero cardinals $\kappa_1$, $\kappa_2$, we have that $\kappa_1\cdot \kappa_2=\max(\kappa_1,\kappa_2)$ as soon as one of the two is infinite. Therefore in that case you cannot make anything out of $\kappa=\alpha\cdot \kappa$, as far as evaluating $\alpha$ is concerned.

Comment: No, infinite cardinals do not work that way. (For example, $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ have the same cardinality.) Just write out the definition of $[G:G]$.

Comment: So, something like: we know that G is a subgroup of G, now we have to find the left cosets of G. We have that: eG=G is a left coset of G, but since eG=G we have that [G:G]=1

Comment: Since $gG=G$ for each $g\in G$, the coset space $G/G$ is just the singleton $\{G\}$, which clearly has cardinality $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$[G : G]$ is the number of cosets $g G$ in $G$. I claim that there’s only one such coset, i.e. $g G = G$ for all $g \in G$.

For a fixed $g \in G$, consider $x \in G$. Then $x = g \left( g^{-1} x \right) \in gG$. Thus $G \subseteq g G \subseteq G$. This means there’s only one coset, namely $G$, so $[G : G] = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we always have

$$|G| = [G:H]|H|$$

Recall that $G$ is partitioned by the cosets $G/H = \{gH: g \in G\}$. Thus

$$|G| = \left|\bigcup G/H\right| = \sum_{x \in G/H} |x| = |G/H||x| = [G:H]|H| $$

where we used that $|gH| = |H|$ for $g \in G$.

---

In your case, you don't need the previous. We have that $[G:G]$ is the amount of cosets of $G$ in $G$. Since $G=eG$, there is exactly one such coset and thus $[G:G]=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$[G:H]$ is just the number of cosets of the subgroup $H$ in the group $G.$ In the case of $[G:G],$ what cosets could there be besides $G$ itself?